# Is it possible to pass parameters in the Hudson's job that will be triggered remotely?

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson

I need to pass a few parameters in the job that will be triggered remotely.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Hudson Wiki has a page about [parameterized builds](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Hudson-ci/Using_Hudson/Parameterized_Builds#Launching_a_build_with_parameters), which includes:

```
A build can be started just by accessing:
http://server/job/myjob/buildWithParameters?PARAMETER=Value
```

Answer (score 1):

Hudson's JOB has an option:

```
Build Environment -> Configure M2 Extra Build Steps -> Add post-build step -> Execute Shell
```

So, you can execute wget by this option in this way:

```
wget="http://server/job/myjob/buildWithParameters?PARAMETER1=Value1\&PARAMETER2=Value2"
```

Try it! I have used it and it works! :)

Comment: If you're using a Run Parameter, you make it work via `&SelectedRun=myjobname#12345`