# submitting a parameterized hudson build via the REST API

Tags: hudson

hudson supports submitting a build by doing an HTTP GET to an API. I need to pass some parameters to such a build. Just adding them as additional URL parameters doesn't work for me. Is this supposed to work? Is there some other mechanism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Is it possible to pass parameters in the Hudson's job that will be triggered remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198895/is-it-possible-to-pass-parameters-in-the-hudsons-job-that-will-be-triggered-remo)
Check this question.
Instead of /build use /buildWithParameters. I'm currently using it with a simple wget

Answer (score 1):

Based on the HTML source on the web interface for starting a parameterized build, you need to do a POST to `http://hudson/job/NAME/build` with the parameters.

**Update:** It's a little more complicated. There's a hidden input with name "name" and value "MyParameter", then the input you actually fill in with name "value" and value "MyInput". (Where MyParameter if your parameter name and MyInput is whatever you need to fill in.) I haven't checked to see how this works with more than one parameter.

the POST works with just the json url parameter that contains a JSON list of the build parameters: json=%7B%22parameter%22%3A+%5B%7B%22name%22%3A+%22Input%22%2C+%22value%22%3A+%22data1%22%7D%2C+%7B%22name%22%3A+%22Input2%22%2C+%22value%22%3A+%22data2%22%7D%5D%2C+%7D

Comment: Worse yet. The json param seems to be required.

Comment: Agreed. It's not pretty. For me the POST works with just the json url parameter that contains a JSON list of the build parameters: `json=%7B%22parameter%22%3A+%5B%7B%22name%22%3A+%22Input%22%2C+%22value%22%3A+%22data1%22%7D%2C+%7B%22name%22%3A+%22Input2%22%2C+%22value%22%3A+%22data2%22%7D%5D%2C+%7D`