# automating hudson builds with ant throwing 403

Tags: ant, authentication, hudson

We have a hudson server which deploys builds. We have a few services which we want to be able to remotely tell hudson to deploy a certain build ... these services are using ant. So I'm trying to get it working but keeping getting a 403 response when giving a build number like so...

```
<ac:post    to="http://hostname:8080/hudson/job/test_release_indexes/build?"
    verbose="true" wantresponse="true">
        <prop name="token" value="indexes"/>
        <prop name="BUILDNUMBER" value="0354"/>
</ac:post>
```

this throws the 403. I've also tried passing it props for the username and password like so ...

```
<ac:post to="http://srulesre2:8080/hudson/job/test_dartmouth_indexes/build?"
    verbose="true" wantresponse="true">
        <prop name="token" value="indexes"/>
        <prop name="BUILDNUMBER" value="0354"/>
        <prop name="username" value="test"/>
        <prop name="password" value="test"/>
</ac:post>
```

I've tried a hundred different variations on username and password ... like j_username and j_password or user and pass ... but nothing is working ... keep getting the same 403. And the username and password are valid because I can manually log in with admin privileges. Any ideas would be great

Answer (score 0):

Can you do a view source on the Hudson login screen to see what fields the form takes? I dont have a running instance myself.

Comment: So I thought the same thing and seen that it takes j_username and j_password as fields for logging in. So I tried to do a post with the login screen like so

  <ac:post to="http://<servername>:8080/hudson/login?    from=/hudson/log/all"
  verbose="true" wantresponse="true">
   <prop name="j_username" value="test"/>
   <prop name="j_password" value="test"/>
  </ac:post>

but still get a 403.

Comment: In my experience, there's a script that wraps form parameters into json. You might need to try something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201843/submitting-a-parameterized-hudson-build-via-the-rest-api/2202137#2202137

Comment: Or if you look at Ant Fikin which specifically has examples for posting username/password http://fikin-ant-tasks.sourceforge.net/fikin-ant-tasks.html#httppost

Comment: I tried the Ant Fikin task and still get the same 403 error. If it makes any difference the logs say that "No valid crumb was included in the request"

Comment: Could it be a Hudson bug for specific versions as here http://n4.nabble.com/JIRA-Created-HUDSON-5717-No-valid-crumb-on-manual-build-request-td1561925.html

Comment: That's possible ... However as of yesterday night we've given up that route and gone another way ... a bit more cumbersome bit it works. Dave I tried getting it done with json but it simply was not working and I can't spend any more time on it. I'll just chalk this up to hudson not being as user friendly as it should. But thanks anyway guys.